# Fatal error: FileIterator contains 1 abstract method must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, fatal-error, abstract-class

I need to add a custom shipping method. I was fallowging this tutorial: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/
I am receiving this error:

> Fatal error: Class Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator contains 1
>   abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods (Countable::se) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\FileIterator.php

Any ideas? I am not finding this interface in the code I added fallowing the steps. Thanks

Comment: On which step you are facing this error? while enabling module?

Comment: i guess you have not compiled your code after making some changes, try php bin/magento setup:di:compile command and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @NaveedAsim it seems that command solve my problem. Courious thing is that this is not mentioned in any tutorial I have read about add new module, and stuff like that.